# How to display several columns of sql results from the same column in one search

Tags: php, mysql, sql

It's hard to explain, so I will show. Here is my sample data:

CallRecords table:

```
CallerID    CallLength    Date
--------    ----------    ----
1000        200         2016-03-28
1001        300         2016-03-28
1000        450         2016-03-28
1002        600         2016-03-28
1002        610         2016-03-28
1001        340         2016-03-28
1000        400         2016-03-28
1001        444         2016-03-28
1002        100         2016-03-28
1000        280         2016-03-28
1002        670         2016-03-28
1000        200         2016-03-28
1001        300         2016-03-28
1001        450         2016-03-28
1000        600         2016-03-28
1002        610         2016-03-28
1000        340         2016-03-29
1000        400         2016-03-29
1002        444         2016-03-29
1000        140         2016-03-29
1001        280         2016-03-29
1001        670         2016-03-29
1002        400         2016-03-29
1002        444         2016-03-29
1001        140         2016-03-29
1001        280         2016-03-29
1000        670         2016-03-29
```

What I want to display as output from the query:

```
CallerID   #Calls<3Min  Duration  #Calls3-5Min  Duration  #Calls>5Min  Duration
--------   -----------  --------  -----------   --------  -----------  --------
1000        1           140        3             680       6          2860
1001        1           140        4             1160      4          1904
1002        1           100        0             0         7          3778
```

I have tried using multiple select statements, and it takes a long time (my database is actually much bigger obviously) and is rather convoluted. Is there an easy way to frame the query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`, and use `case` expressions to do conditional `count`/`sum`:

```
select CallerID,
       count(case when CallLength < 180 then 1 end) as "#Calls<3Min",
       sum(case when CallLength < 180 then CallLength else 0 end) as "Duration 3min's",
       ...
from tablename
group by CallerID
```